# What's the meaning of "rc" in the config file names

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript universe there's lots of config files such as "babelrc", "mocharc", "eslintrc". What is the meaning of "rc" in the name? Is this an acronym?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030552/what-does-rc-mean-in-dot-files#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20Unix,%2DSharing%20System%20(CTSS).

Comment: Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212256/what-are-rc-files-in-nodejs) SO question, it has detailed answer.

Comment: There is a SO-Question with good answers regarding the use of rc-files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212256/what-are-rc-files-in-nodejs).
Acoording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030552/what-does-rc-mean-in-dot-files) Post, it most likely means 'runtime configuration'.