# File type association (syntax highlighter) for .rc file

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting, file-association, rc, pylintrc

What is the correct file type association for a [`.rc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030552/what-does-rc-mean-in-dot-files) in PyCharm?

---

**What I Found**

[Syntax highlighter for config files (.cfg, .ini, .rc)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206814175-Syntax-highlighter-for-config-files-cfg-ini-rc-closed-)

Suggests using the [`Ini` plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6981-ini), however in my opinion, a `.rc` file is not a `.ini` file.

---

**My Specific Use Case**

In my specific use case, I have a `.pylintrc` file. I am unsure of what to pick, currently, I just selected `Text`.

[image: pylint rc file]

Here is `pylint`'s example `.pylintrc` file: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/examples/pylintrc

I'm using PyCharm PE 2020.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick `INI config` File Type.

In PyCharm go to `Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> File Types -> INI Config` and add to `File name patterns` `.pylintrc` file and if it asks - reassign from `Text` association to `INI`.

Example:

[image: Settings File Types]

P.S. I have the same [ini plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6981-ini). And I made this trick just to answer your question. It works.